# How to Create a LInked Server to SQL Server on Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want to create a linked server from Oracle to SQL Server.  I’ve searched the internet, but I can’t find a way to do this.  Also, what is the synonym of a linked server in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4396084), it describes how to do it.

This is not as easy as using `create database link`.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you could summarise the link.